# Trading view pinescript label overlaps

Tags: label, pine-script

When I create label for my indicator, they are to many and they overlaps.
Someone know how to make a label on top when we put the cursor on ? Or an other solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HiBc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to keep their required width to the minimum. Your first line is taking up lots of space that you could probably reduce or split on 2 lines.

Then you can alternate placement from top to bottom of candles, or simply vary the y position of contiguous labels so they have fewer chances of overlapping.

Lastly, you can make their background invisible.

Comment: Hi LucF, I have read your solution and with these i found an other thing that answer to my issue, it is "size=size.auto" :)

Comment: Good idea! Happy for you. gl with the project.